# How to optimize data loading in Ionic 4 - Angular 7 App

Tags: angular, angular-material, ionic4

I have an object with 1000 items into it.

I am loading those data in the UI but application is not able to handle that large volume of data.

Is there any approach to manage huge data in Angular?

Here is my code:

*Controller*

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { bouquetList } from '../../assets/bouquet';

    interface BouquetInfo {
      name: string;
      mrp: number;
      channel: string[];
    }

    export interface Bouquet {
      broadcaster: {
        name: string;
        bouquet: BouquetInfo[];
      };
    }

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-bouquet',
      templateUrl: './bouquet.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./bouquet.page.scss'],
    })
    export class BouquetPage implements OnInit {

      bouquets: Bouquet[] = bouquetList; // assiging a const of large data

      constructor() { }


    }
```

*html*

```html
<mat-accordion>
        <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let bouquet of bouquets" >
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>
                    {{bouquet.broadcaster.name}} | 
         {{bouquet.broadcaster.bouquet.length }}
                </mat-panel-title>
                <mat-panel-description>
                </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>

            <div *ngIf="!currentBouquet[0]; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
            <ng-template #thenBlock>Loading...</ng-template>

            <ng-template #elseBlock>
                <mat-accordion>
                    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let channel of bouquet.broadcaster.bouquet">
                      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <mat-panel-title>
                            {{channel.name}}
                        </mat-panel-title>
                        <mat-panel-description>
                            {{channel.mrp | currency: 'INR' }}
                        </mat-panel-description>
                      </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                      <mat-list role="list"  *ngFor="let item of channel.channel; let i=index">
                          <mat-list-item role="listitem">{{i + 1}}. {{item}}</mat-list-item>
                        </mat-list>


                    </mat-expansion-panel>
                  </mat-accordion>
            </ng-template>


        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
```

*UI* for your idea

[image]

Comment: infinite scroll? did you try something like that?

Comment: I want to show the item name of the top level list first. & then I have to show the sub item.

Answer (score 0):

I'd generate a top-level-only index, offload the main data to something like Firebase, then query on the index for the main record. It's super-fast.